# How to test pasted content when using `useClipboard` hook in ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, chakra-ui

I have a component that has a copy button that copies some data to the clipboard.

I would like to test that the correct data has been copied to the clipboard using `jest` & `@testing-library/react`

This is the component's implementation:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, useClipboard } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { formatData } from "@/lib/formatters";

export const MyComponent = ({ data }: Data) => {
  const { hasCopied, onCopy } = useClipboard(formatData(data));
  return <Button onClick={onCopy}>{hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy Data"}</Button>;
};
```

And here is the unit test

```js
it("copies data to clipboard", () => {
  render(<MyComponent data={data} />);
  screen.getByRole("button").click();
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Copy Data" }));
  // Expect that the clipboard data is set to the formatted data
  expect(navigator.clipboard.readText()).toEqual(formatData(data)); // Doesn't work!
});
```

However, when I run the unit test, I get an error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'readText')`

Is there a way to elegantly test the pasted content?

PS: `useClipboard` is using `copy-to-clipboard` package under the hood, which could be mocked, but that solution wouldn't be so elegant.

Comment: Can you show the code of `useClipboard` hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jest is running the tests with [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) and jsdom doesn't support `navigator.clipborad`, this is why `clipboard` is `undefined` and cannot read property `writeText` of undefined. However react testing library [replaces `window.navigator.clipboard` with a stub](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/clipboard/) when `userEvent.setup()` is used.

If your implementation was using `navigator.clipboard` instead of [copy-to-clipboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard)

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }: Data) => {
  const [hasCopied, setHasCopied] = React.useState(false)
  const val = formatData(data)

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(val).then(() => {
        setHasCopied(true)
      });
    }}>{hasCopied ? "Copied!" : "Copy Data"}</Button>
  );
};
```

you would have been able to expect:

```
test("should return text, reading the clipboard text", async () => {

  const user = userEvent.setup()

  render(<App />)
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/copy data/i)
  user.click(linkElement)

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(linkElement).toHaveTextContent('Copied!')
  })

  await expect(navigator.clipboard.readText()).resolves.toEqual("{\"hello\":\"world\"}")
})
```

---

but since `execCommand` is used instead of the `navigator.clipboard` API it would have to be mocked as well, as it's not supported by [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)

to mock it I would use the already prepared stub by react testing library like this

```
let user: ReturnType<typeof userEvent.setup>;

beforeAll(() => {
  user = userEvent.setup();

  Object.assign(document, {
    execCommand: (cmd: string) => {
      switch (cmd) {
        case "copy":
          user.copy();
          return true;
        case "paste":
          user.paste();
          return;
      }
    },
  });
});
```

and the above test should work once again

Comment: Seems promising thanks! The tests pass indeed. However, I'm having one new issue: 
`Warning: The current testing environment is not configured to support act(...)`
pointing at the `onCopy`. I'm using NextJS

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.clipboard.readText(`) returns a **promise**, not a **string**. [MDN-Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText)

That's why `expect(navigator.clipboard.readText()).toEqual(formatData(data))` isn't working.

```js
// MOCK CLIPBOARD

const mockClipboard = {
  writeText: jest.fn(),
  readText: jest.fn(),
};
global.navigator.clipboard = mockClipboard;

it('copies data to clipboard', async () => {
  render(<MyComponent data={data} />);
 // Reset the mock functions before each test
  mockClipboard.writeText.mockReset();
 mockClipboard.readText.mockReset().mockResolvedValue(formattedData);

  const copyButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Copy Data' });
  fireEvent.click(copyButton);
  await waitFor(() => {
  expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith(formattedData);
  });
  const clipboardContent = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  expect(clipboardContent).toEqual(formattedData);
  expect(copyButton).toHaveTextContent('Copied!');
});
```

Comment: I also tried with await before, with no luck.
```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')```. Unfortunately your answer isn't helpful.

Comment: Check if the Clipboard API is available in the test environment (JSDOM).

Comment: Seems like it's not available and it's a known issue https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1568

How would you mock it?

Comment: Updated the answer EDIT: added mock functions.

Comment: I tried your updated solution and I get `Error: Not implemented: window.prompt` + TS error `Cannot assign to 'clipboard' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)`